# Better Waves in java

Tags: java

I'm making a game where the player fires waves(like tidal waves not harmonics) and I have a system in pace where I achieve it moving for a distance and it dies off. It also bounces off of entities (not very well I might add). I want to know if there is a way to make this more realistic and seperable rather than it complete changes.
Here is the curve( I'm using slick2d).

```
one = new Vector2f((float)referenceX, (float) referenceY);
two = new Vector2f((float) (referenceX + ((width * amplitude) / Math.PI)), (float)(referenceY - (height * amplitude)));
three = new Vector2f((float) ((referenceX + width) - ((width * amplitude) / Math.PI)), (float)(referenceY - (height * amplitude)));
four = new Vector2f((float)(referenceX + width),(float)(referenceY));`
new Curve(one, two, three, four);
```

It moves by moving the reference points and extending the width.

here is the collision code

```
if ((s.player.getBounds().getWidth() / 2) + s.player.getBounds().getX() > 
                (e.getBounds().getX() + e.getBounds().getWidth()) )
{
    this.referenceX = e.getBounds().getX() + (e.getBounds().getWidth() / 4);
    this.referenceY = e.getBounds().getY();
}
else if ((s.player.getBounds().getWidth() / 2) + s.player.getBounds().getX() <
                e.getBounds().getX())
{
    this.referenceX = e.getBounds().getX();
    this.referenceY = e.getBounds().getY();
}
else
{
    this.referenceX = s.player.getBounds().getX() + 4;
    this.referenceY = e.getBounds().getY();
}
```

What and how should I fix this to make the waves seem more realistic?

Comment: I'm not sure there's enough information here.  Can you be more specific about what the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code, I'm guessing that the waves don't look like they are expanding away from the player correctly, and are probably not bouncing well.  Even if your waves bounce off the simplest entities, like a straight wall perpendicular to the path of the wave, you will find it hard to represent the wave in a realistic manner using a curve, or even a bunch of curves.  I think you will find it much easier to model the waves in more of a ray-casting way:

Instead of the player shooting a wave, think of them shooting a fixed number of particles:

- A wave is a collection of particles (it doesn't have to be a big number)
- If the player shoots at 45 degrees, with a wave 'width' of 10 degrees, think of their wave as 11 points leaving from the player with angles 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, ... 50.  The longer your wave is going to last, or the further it may travel, the more points you may need to model it smoothly.
- Each point is an object that has an angle, or path, and a distance it has traveled
- During each time increment, calculate the new location for the point using its path and distance (it might slow down as it goes further, or slow down each time it bounces, die after a certain distance, or even model 'wave absorbing' walls)
- Make each point object responsible for handling its collisions and acting accordingly: when a particle hits an object, calculate its new angle or path.
- When it comes time to draw the wave run a curve or line segments through the particle points in order.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. My problem with using a lot of points( times the number of waves that could be out) would be memory and framerate. That sounds good and it will probably run poorly on a lot of computers but my computer will probably handle it. I will optimize it in the future. Thank you for the advice